# How to stop mongodb server on Windows?

Tags: windows, mongodb, service, command-line

I'm using the nginx/PHP/MongoDB stack and trying to set up my development environment on Windows by creating two batch files.

start.bat

```
cd C:\www\nginx
start nginx
cd C:\www\php
start php-cgi.exe -b 127.0.0.1:9000
cd C:\www\mongodb
start mongod
```

stop.bat

```
cd C:\www\nginx
nginx -s quit
cd C:\www\php
taskkill /F /IM php-cgi.exe
cd C:\www\mongodb
mongo --eval "use admin; db.shutdownServer(); quit"  # this doesn't work
mongo --eval stop_mongod.js  # this doesn't work either
```

Using taskkill to stop mongod isn't an option, since that may lead to data corruption.
Any suggestions?

Comment: you can stop manually using "services.msc" from cmd and select the mongodb service in that list and stop it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the mongo shell [documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Scripting+the+shell):

---

use dbname

This command does not work in scripted mode. Instead you will need to explicitly define the database in the connection (/dbname in the example above).

Alternately, you can also create a connection within the script:

```
db2 = connect("server:27017/otherdbname")
```

---

I've come up with the following code:
Save the following snippet in **stop_mongod.js** file:

```
 db = connect("localhost:27017/admin");
 db.shutdownServer();
 quit();
```

Adjust the connection string if necessary. Then from the command line or within your batch script:

```
mongo stop_mongod.js
```

Answer (score 36):

I'm not sure that's a proper way to do, sending a kill could probably cause damage to your mongo server, and you'll need to repair your database after in case of crash.

Maybe you already solved this question but here is what I do :

```
mongo admin --eval "db.shutdownServer()"
```

I'm automatically connected on the admin's collection and next, I just have to run the extinction.

Here is the official link about how to stop Mongodb properly : http://api.mongodb.org/wiki/current/Starting%20and%20Stopping%20Mongo.html

Best

Comment: 'mongo admin --eval "db.shutdownServer()"' should also do it.

Comment: This worked well for me doing ad-hoc maintenance on some Mongo-on-Windows instances. It was more reliable than using Windows "net stop" cmd.

Comment: But now I cannot start it back up using tips from here: https://medium.com/stackfame/run-mongodb-as-a-service-in-windows-b0acd3a4b712

Answer (score 29):

1. Open Command Prompt/Powershell as Administrator.
2. Execute

   net stop MongoDB

Comment: Is there a `status` for the `net` command in powershell?

Answer (score 14):

Open Command prompt as an administrator

```
net stop mongodb
```

Comment: I found this helpful!

Answer (score 12):

If the server is running as the foreground process in a terminal, this
can be done by pressing

```
Ctrl-C
```

Another way to cleanly shut down a running server is to use the shutdown command,

```
> use admin
> db.shutdownServer();
```

Answer (score 5):

From the Windows command line. I'm using MongoDB 3.4 Server on 64-bit Windows 7 Pro SP1.

The following links explain the steps:

[configure-a-windows-service-for-mongodb-community-edition](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#configure-a-windows-service-for-mongodb-community-edition)

[manually-create-a-windows-service-for-mongodb-community-edition](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#manually-create-a-windows-service-for-mongodb-community-edition)

The following console command line terminates MongoDB at start-up:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Windows\System32>"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin\mongod.exe" --remove
2017-12-06T08:15:47.883-0600 I CONTROL  [main] Trying to remove Windows service 'MongoDB'
2017-12-06T08:15:47.884-0600 I CONTROL  [main] Service 'MongoDB' removed
```

The MongoDB service create command line (shown below) is located in the Windows registry here:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\MongoDB
```

To check, do the following:

```
C:\Windows\System32>sc.exe create MongoDB binPath= "\"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin\mongod.exe\" --service --c
onfig=\"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\mongod.cfg\"" DisplayName= "MongoDB" start= "auto"
[SC] CreateService SUCCESS

C:\Windows\System32>net start MongoDB
The MongoDB service is starting.
The MongoDB service was started successfully.

C:\Windows\System32>net stop MongoDB
The MongoDB service is stopping.
The MongoDB service was stopped successfully.

C:\Windows\System32>"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin\mongod.exe" --remove
2017-12-06T08:16:36.504-0600 I CONTROL  [main] Trying to remove Windows service 'MongoDB'
2017-12-06T08:16:36.505-0600 I CONTROL  [main] Service 'MongoDB' removed

C:\Windows\System32>
```

Answer (score 5):

If you install mongodb as a service on windows. you can stop the service using following command in elevated command prompt

```
 net stop mongodb
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess, using TASKKILL /IM mongod.exe is fine to terminate the mongodb server gracefully.